# Sorted NSMutableArray and Remove Object

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a NSMutableArray populated with custom objects and I have to sort.
I have read that it is possible to sort a NSMutableArray using the following code.

```
NSSortDescriptor * sortDescriptor;
sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: @ "name" ascending: YES];
NSArray * sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject: sortDescriptor];
[array sortUsingDescriptors: sortDescriptors];
```

In doing so, however, I have a problem, since I have to delete the elements within dell'NSMutableArray, and if I try with the method [removeObject] I get an error because I can not delete objects from an NSArray
Is there a way to solve this problem?
Thank you,
Vincenzo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invoke `mutableCopy` on an `NSArray` object to return to you an `NSMutableArray` like this:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [array mutableCopy];
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got something wrong here... NSMutableArray's sortUsingDescriptors: sorts the array itself. It doesn't return an NSArray - it sorts the instance "in place": https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/sortUsingDescriptors:

So your code would be:

```
NSMutableArray * myArray = ...
[myArray sortUsingDescriptors:@[[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: @ "name" ascending: YES]]];
[myArray removeObjectAtIndex:...]; // or any other method you like
```